# MethodNotAllowedHttpException while update record in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've recently joined Laravel framework so firstly i trying to make a CRUD system in laravel, for understanding their fundamentals their functionality.

Now here i've face a error ***MethodNotAllowedHttpException*** at the time of updating existing record.

**Here in my routes**

```
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
```

**Which gives me the following list of possible routes**

```
| GET|HEAD  | product                    | product.index          | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@index   
| POST      | product                    | product.store          | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store    
| GET|HEAD  | product/create             | product.create         | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@create     
| GET|HEAD  | product/{product}          | product.show           | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@show        
| DELETE    | product/{product}          | product.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@destroy        
| PUT|PATCH | product/{product}          | product.update         | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@update      
| GET|HEAD  | product/{product}/edit     | product.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@edit
```

**Editform view**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
@section('title','Product List')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
<form action="{{url('product/'.$product['id'])}}" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{ method_field('PUT')}}
    <!-- <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"> -->
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="{{$product['name']}}" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">category</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{$product['category']}}"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="category" placeholder="">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">weight</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{$product['weight']}}"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="weight" placeholder="">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">price</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{$product['price']}}"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="price" placeholder="">

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

**ProductController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, $product_id)
{
    $created = product::create($request->all());
   if($created){
    return redirect('product')->with('message','data added');
   }
}
```

In this situation, whenever i wan to change existing records data by refiling edit form. it generates *MethodNotAllowedHttpException* error.

i tried lots of solutions but it not fixed. So please guide where i am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you are using the wrong HTTP method for updating existing record. You need to specify method as `PUT` via method spoofing.
Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="{{ route('product.update', $product['id']) }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('PUT')}}    //method Spoofing
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="{{ $product['name'] }}" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">category</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{$product['category']}}"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="category" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">weight</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{$product['weight']}}"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="weight" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">price</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{$product['price']}}"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="price" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> //input type, not button
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, added. but its gives no response. my URL bar fill with their changed data..!

Comment: Show your full form

Comment: sorry, which fill form you want?

Comment: <form> ... </form>

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For `update()` you need to use `PUT` method. So, add this line to the form:

```
<input name="_method" value="PUT" type="hidden">
```

Comment: ok, added. but its gives no response. my URL bar fill with their changed data..!

Comment: you are doing the redirection only if created. cover the case when it's not created

Comment: Maybe quote a [bit from docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing) how it works

Comment: @BugInspector ljubadr is right, you're redirecting only when `$created` is `true`

Comment: it fixed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in

```
<form action="{{url('product/'.$product['id'])}}" class="form-horizontal">
```

I solved this declaring the form with method="POST" in it, and then:  {{ method_field('PUT')}}

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
@section('title','Product List')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
<form method="POST" action="{{url('product/'.$product['id'])}}" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{ method_field('PUT')}}
    <!-- <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"> -->
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="{{$product['name']}}" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">category</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{$product['category']}}"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="category" placeholder="">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">weight</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{$product['weight']}}"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="weight" placeholder="">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">price</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{$product['price']}}"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="price" placeholder="">

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```